# How do you open a zipped PDF from a browser link?

Tags: html, unzip

Using the MS Edge browser on Windows 11 ... I have a directory with three PDF files, two of which are inside a zip file:

- file1.pdf
- myfile.zip/file2.pdf
- myfile.zip/file3.pdf

I want to access these from a static HTML page.  Something like ...

```
<a href="file1.pdf" target="_new1">file1</a>
<a href="myfile.zip\file2.pdf" target="_new2">file2</a>
<a href="myfile.zip\file3.pdf" target="_new3">file3</a>
```

Obviously, while the first link works, the other two don't.  Is there a way to do this?

(Note: This isn't my regular skill area.  So, 'semi-newbie' answers, please.)

UPDATE:  I did simplify the scenario to keep the question simple.  Actually, there are over 1000 PDFs in a directory tree (some in ZIPS, some not).  These are all subject to being updated by an external process on an ad-hoc basis.  If not for that then, yes, simply unzipping everything would be the easiest approach.  Maybe the best solution *is* to routinely scan the directories for changed ZIPs and unzip any updated ones ... but I wanted to see if there was a better way: either access directly (if possible) or some sort of JIT unzip when a link is clicked.

Comment: Semi newbie answer: Thats not possible. A "zip" is a file itself, and can not be handled like directory/folder. You have to unzip it first to access the content inside it.

Answer (score 1):

A ZIP file is not a directory, but is a file itself.

It is highly recommended that you unzip the ZIP file to a folder. For example, you may extract the `myfile.zip` to a directory `myfile` on your server then use codes like:

```
<a href="file1.pdf" target="_new1">file1</a>
<a href="myfile\file2.pdf" target="_new2">file2</a>
<a href="myfile\file3.pdf" target="_new3">file3</a>
```

And if you JUST won't do that, you may try using a Javascript library to unzip files. I searched the Internet and found this one:
[JSZIP](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/)

You may try reading the documentation and add a Javascript to your HTML to extract the ZIP file you can get.

Comment: Hmm ... JSZIP might work for me.  (I've appended an update to my question to explain my rationale.)

Answer (score 0):

Edge is generally restricted in what it can do with secured files thus you cannot address a zips contents directly but you may address a zip folder.

However that folder if it's a zip will be treated as a download and then the cached file will be opened. BUT again be restricted in what is allowed. For example the user may copy and paste to another folder (unzipped of course). That in itself could be done via sendkeys!

[image]

What can you do to view a file in a zip is thus constrained to what you may run in a shell script (i.e. possible from a HTA web page)

To view a pdf from a zip you need vbs\js\ps1\cmd\bat\scripts along the lines of

```
if not exist %temp%\newbe md %temp%\newbe
cd /d %temp%\newbe

tar -xf "C:\long path to\example.zip"

for blah blah "%temp%\newbe\*.PDF" do select one to view

for selected do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="%temp%\newbe\selected.pdf"
```

The alternative approach as you suggest is monitor folder for altered zip then auto extract with tar and echo each new file

```
@echo off
rem cd /d "c:\work dir"

REM this command will extract files with overwrite (list will show "x filename" for extracted)
tar -xvf "example.zip" 2>files.txt

echo ^<html^>^<title^>My New List^</title^>^<body^> >files.html
for /f "tokens=1* delims= " %%v in (files.txt) do echo ^<a href="file:///%cd%/%%w"  target="_blank"^>%%w^</a^>^</br^> >>files.html
echo ^</body^>^</html^> >>files.html
start "My New List" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app="file:///%cd%/files.html"
```

First line redirect (one non escaped chevron) overwrites the list so be cautious, each entry can be built by a simple for loop with >>append and add other lines to suit, just ensure all html `<` or `>` are escaped with `^`

[image]